# How to send an NSString to another view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, nsstring

I have an IBAction that when triggered calls another method in a different view controller (    APICallsViewController). I'm looking to also send that method an NSString (message)

here's my IBAction with the push to the APICallsViewController and also the NSString message. My question might be how do I grab the contents of that NSString in the other view controller's method.

thanks for any help

```
-(IBAction) someMethod{
        APICallsViewController *apiViewController = [[APICallsViewController alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:apiViewController animated:YES]; 

        NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Check out %@", nameLb.text];

        [apiViewController apiGraphUserCheckins];

        [apiViewController release];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this code in APICallsViewController.h

```
@interface APICallsViewController : UIViewController{
   NSString *strMessage;

}
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *strMessage;

@end
```

APICallsViewController.m

```
 @synthesize strMessage;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
Nslog(@"%@",strMessage);
```

}

---

```
-(IBAction) someMethod{

    APICallsViewController *apiViewController = [[APICallsViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:apiViewController animated:YES]; 

    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Check out %@", nameLb.text];
    apiViewController.strMessage=message;
    [apiViewController apiGraphUserCheckins];

    [apiViewController release];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a string in the viewcontroller to where you have to pass the string.And in the view from which you have to pass the string,in your case,set like
 apiViewController.stringintheotherview=message;

The string in your APICallsViewController must be synthesized

```
 NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Check out %@", nameLb.text];
         APICallsViewController *apiViewController = [[APICallsViewController alloc] init];
 apiViewController.stringintheotherview=message;
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:apiViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to pass the String programmatically, instead of declaring a function parameter? You could change the Function to something like

```
- (void) apiGraphUserCheckins:(NSString *)message;
```

call it with

```
[apiViewController apiGraphUserCheckins:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Check out %@", nameLb.text]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a property in SecondViewController. Then you can get string in SecondViewController in 2ways.

1. In FirstViewController someMethod after creating object for secondviewController you can assign the value directly

   > second.string2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [textField text]];
2. Create a method in SecondViewController and assign through it.