# How do I pass objects between objects in objective c and then make sure they don't all get deleted?

Tags: objective-c, class, object, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send an NSString to another view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719017/how-to-send-an-nsstring-to-another-view-controller)

I've made a class (classA) which stores data. classB sends it the data. What happens is that classB sends classA an object then the object is deleted in classB. I think the problem with my program is that when the object is deleted from classB, it is deleted from classA because I guess there is only one real 'copy' of the object. Have I understood it right? How would I solve this problem? I can only think of duplicating the object in classB but it there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: it may be little help..4 u .. <http://stackoverflow.com/a/10719194/1223137>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In objective-c object deletes when it's retain count is equal to 0. So, if your classB want this passed object to exist, just retain it and release after it is not needed. If it is a property, declare property as retain(or strong, uf you using arc).

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to get the object from classB to a retained object in the classA (You can use a property in classA which is retained). Then you will not lose the scope of the object being passed from classA to classB.